# perl xs - can't return a new custom c++ object from method call - returns scalar value instead

Tags: c++, perl, xs

In my XS file I have:

As my new method:

```
matrix *
matrix::new( size_t ncols, size_t nrows )
```

which returns a `matrix` object like it should and I can invoke methods.

Then I have a method call which creates a new matrix object and is supposed to return it as a new matrix:

```
matrix *
matrix::getInnerMatrix( )
    PREINIT:
        char *  CLASS = (char *)SvPV_nolen(ST(0));
    CODE:
        RETVAL = static_cast<matrix*>(THIS->matrix::getInnerMatrix());
    OUTPUT:
        RETVAL
```

However the returned type is `matrix=SCALAR(0x122f81c)` and therefore I am unable to invoke any method calls from this object as the perl interpreter seems to be viewing the returned type as a scalar value type instead of a 'matrix' object.  Here is a test script:

```
$m1 = matrix::new(matrix,4,4);
@arr = ( 1 .. 16 );
$aref = [@arr];
$m1->assign_aref($aref);
my $m2 = $m1->getInnerMatrix();
print ref $m1; # returns "matrix" (like it should)
print "\n\n";
print ref $m2; # returns "matrix=SCALAR(0x122f81c)" (wrong)
```

Here is my typemap:

```
TYPEMAP
matrix *        O_MATRIX

OUTPUT
O_MATRIX
    sv_setref_pv( $arg, CLASS, (void*)$var );

INPUT
O_MATRIX
    if ( sv_isobject($arg) && (SvTYPE(SvRV($arg)) == SVt_PVMG) ) {
        $var = ($type)SvIV((SV*)SvRV( $arg ));
    }
    else {
        warn( \"${Package}::$func_name() -- ${var} not a blessed SV reference\" );
        XSRETURN_UNDEF;
    }
```

What changes must I make in my XS file, or any other file to ensure that a pure `matrix` object is returned?

Comment: Why are you explicitly assigning the `CLASS`? Note that `SvPV_nolen(scalar)` works pretty much like `"$scalar"`, i.e. stringifies the reference which by default looks like `ClassName=HASH(0xabc123)` or similar.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show your typemap for `matrix*` as well?

Comment: I added the line `char *  CLASS = (char *)SvPV_nolen(ST(0));` because before, when I didn't have it in there, I was getting the compiler error `error: 'CLASS' was not declared in this scope sv_setref_pv( RETVALSV, CLASS, (void*)RETVAL );`.  After adding that line, it compiles.

Comment: @amon Just added the typemap.

Comment: PS - Why isn't `new` a method?!

Comment: @ikegami I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: One normally uses `matrix->new(...);` to create an object.

Comment: PS - Lowercase module names are reserved.

Comment: PS - Lowercase module names indicate pragmas. Your module is not a pragma.

Comment: I think your XS for `new` is correct. You just need to replace `$m1 = matrix::new(matrix,4,4);` with `my $m1 = matrix->new(4,4);`. Your version doesn't even work with `use strict;`. **Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!!**

Comment: Thanks for telling all that.  I'll will make those changes.  I'm still new to perl and xs.  My background is extensively in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using XS with C++, the XS preprocessor inserts `THIS` for instance methods and `CLASS` for static methods. A method called `new` is treated as a static method. This allows the resulting xsubs to be used as instance methods/class methods by default: `matrix->new` and `$m->getInnerMatrix()`.

Your typemap uses the `CLASS` variable which is not provided for instance methods. In your case, I would hard-code the package name in the type map instead:

```
OUTPUT
O_MATRIX
    sv_setref_pv( $arg, "matrix", (void*)$var );
```

The typemap is also used when an argument of that type is not used as the invocant. E.g. consider this xsub:

```
matrix*
some_other_xsub(x)
    int x
```

Here there would not by a `CLASS` variable for the `matrix*` return value either.

Note that lowercase package names should only be used for pragma packages (like `strict` or `warnings`). Please use CamelCase for your classes.

Your attempt to provide your own value for `CLASS` failed because `SvPV_nolen()` stringifies the reference and does not get the reference type. I.e. it's equivalent to `"$m"`, not to `ref $m`. A more correct alternative would have been to use `sv_ref()`:

```
char* CLASS = SvPV_nolen(sv_ref(NULL, THIS, true));
```

The third parameter to `sv_ref()` makes this function work like the Perl function `ref`, i.e. return the class name if the scalar is blessed, not just the underlying reference type.

Comment: After I changed `sv_setref_pv( $arg, CLASS, (void*)$var );` to `sv_setref_pv( $arg, "matrix", (void*)$var );` in my typemap file, I no longer needed to add that extra line in the the `xs` file.

Comment: @amon, Hardcoding `matrix` prevents inheritance. Leaving the typemap unchanged and using your later solution (`char* CLASS = SvPV_nolen(sv_ref(NULL, THIS, true));`) is best.

Comment: @ikegami inheritance across language boundaries is quite tricky, and I would strongly recommend against it if possible. I'd rather treat XS-wrapped classes as final than deal with the possible failure modes. You are right though that at least in the constructor, depending on `CLASS` would be preferable. But for non-constructor functions, blessing return values into a subclass would sidestep subclass constructors which might be a bigger problem.